# Is it valid on machine which is not 16 bit

Tags: c

I have been asked in an interview is it valid declaration on a machine which is not 16 bit??

Below is the declaration,

```
 unsigned int zero = 0;
 unsigned int compzero = 0xFFFF;
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They are both *valid* declarations, yes, inasmuch as there's no syntax error.

However, if your intent is to get the complement of `0` (all bits inverted), you should use:

```
unsigned int zero = 0;
unsigned int compzero = ~zero;
```

With (for example) a 32-bit `unsigned int`, `0xffff` and `~0` are respectively:

```
0000 0000 0000 0000 1111 1111 1111 1111
1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111
```

Comment: And suppose we have signed int then can intialize it to -1 ??

Comment: @Amit, yes, if you're using two's complement. But that's only _one_ of the three schemes allowable under ISO C for representing negative numbers (albeit the most common by a long way).

Comment: I didn't see any mention of C (ISO or not) anywhere. Are you assuming this, or do I simply need glasses?

Comment: @Neowizard: glasses, I think. I suggest you look at the tags :-)

Comment: Just for safety, note that `~zero` cannot be replaced with `~0`, but instead must be replaced with `~0u`, for equality. (That is, signed versus unsigned matters!)

Comment: @paxdiablo thanks for the note. Makes things that much clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes the deceleration is valid. Think about it this way, a hex literal is no different then a decimal literal. If they wanted the result of the hex converted to decimal to be zero, then this might not be the case (depends on which system is in use and which negative-number system is in use: 1's complement, 2's complement or a simple Not operator)